# How to unlock victory achievements in Pandora First Contact

Tags: achievements, pandora-first-contact

In [Pandora](http://store.steampowered.com/app/287580/) as in many Steam games are a list of achievements featuring many different things you can do in the game.

However, it seems some of them are not always unlocked even when the prerequisites are met.

For example, I just won a military victory but haven't received the achievement. But the achievement for refitting a unit has been unlocked. What may cause this difference?

I start games without any mods, with the real paid game, from the new game advanced menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [posted by on of the devs](http://steamcommunity.com/app/287580/discussions/0/45350244892919744/#c45350791312926799):

> Victory-based achievements can only be unlocked in single-player games started from the New Game panel (without clicking Advanced) to discourage cheating.

I'd hazard the advanced panel allows for customization of the game which may allow abuse.